# how to install kcachegrind on linux or cirrus?

Tags: callgrind, kcachegrind

I am working on a cirrus machine, having my C code profiled. I have Valgrind installed on it. But the output I get from `--tool=callgrind` is barely understandable, hence I want to use kcachegrind tool. But I am not able to find a link to install it on linux terminal/cirrus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cirrus is not the name of a machine is the name of the cluster you are trying to work on.

So once being there, 
first you need to load the Valgrind module otherwise commands are not recognized by the compiler.

```
$ module load valgrind
```

Have a check here:

https://hpc-uit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/debugging.html